# Animating car wheels, Separating object, Splitting a UV map

Tags: animation, uv

I'm animating the wheels of a car. I can select the wheel in edit mode as shown but not in object mode.  When I separate the wheel from the car to rotate it the uv map for the wheel disappears but the rest of the uv map remains. There is one uv map for the car parts. I hope I'm being clear. Can anyone help please[image]? I want to rotate the wheel with current uv mapping.

[image]

Comment: The uv map for the wheel should not disappear, could you please share your file, don't forget to pack the image so that it's part of the file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you rotate the wheel in edit mode the coordinates of the verticies with respect to the UV are going to be rotated. I think you should be able to separate the wheels into a new mesh, then [TAB] out of edit mode and rotate the wheel. Just going by your pictures.

Answer (score 0):

When posting a question like this, it is best to give us the entire workspace with the elements involved exposed.
Like this...
[image]

You UV Islands may be disappearing because the wheels use a different material than the body of the car and that mesh isn't part of the selected mesh object or material (especially if you've split the wheel away from the car.)

Can you post a picture of your work area like above?

Also, are you trying to rotate vertices in the 3d Viewer or the UV island?  (I'm assuming you're trying to line up the spokes of the front left wheel with the other wheels.)